# Datatype not preserved in dictionary

Tags: python

Hi I'm having trouble storing a datetime object in a dictionary in python. When I try to retrieve the datetime object to compare with another datetime object the returned object is a str not a datetime.

```
class Course(models.Model):
   StartDate = models.DateTimeField()

dict = {}
myDate = Course.StartDate
dict['date'] = myDate

today = datetime.datetime.today()
if today > dict['date']:
   pass
```

assume Course.StartDate returns a datetime object.

Comment: What is Course.StartDate? Also, how do you know you're getting a string back?

Comment: Don't call your dictionary `dict`. Apart from that, your code works as expected. What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError can't compare datetime.datetime to str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look you're missing something in your code here, because what you're trying to do works just fine.

With this model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    # auto_now_add for convenience when testing
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I created an object:

```
>>> c = Course.objects.create()
```

And created a dictionary:

```
>>> mydict = {}
```

Assigned the `start_date` attribute to a dictionary key:

```
>>> mydict['date'] = c.start_date
```

Access the value as a `datetime` object:

```
>>> mydict['date']
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 16, 55, 49, 723208)
```

And can compare the dictionary value to a `datetime` object:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.today() > mydict['date']
True
```

Comment: Well the comparison is done with c.start_date > mydict['date'] in the actual code.